# How do I export my logo in 110 * 40 size using adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, export

I'm not a graphic designer. I got a logo made by a freelance designer on Fiverr long back.

I have the ai files, I recently change the theme of my WordPress website which demands that logo size should be 110 * 40
I reduced the artboard to the specified size.  When I export it, the quality of the logo becomes really bad. What do I do? Please help.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: 110px x 40px? It's a small size, most likely it won't look sharp if you zoom in. How bad does it look like, can you post an image in the question? what file format are you exporting to? Have you checked the Pixel Preview in Illustrator? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I have added the image. The format is jpeg. Although I tried multiple export options already.

Comment: The image you added is 105x40. Regardless, it's a tiny image with quite a lot of detail, it's as sharp as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting to 220x80px (aka 2x or even higher at 330x120) and upload that. If the theme has hardcoded the logo size, it will appear in the same size, but with better details on modern screens, like Retina or HiDPI displays.

Or export to SVG (vector format) and try to upload that. Not sure if WP allows that.